# Drop-down menu disappears too fast because of an arrow

Tags: html, css

I created a navigation with a drop-down menu and above it there is an arrow.

To the arrow looks the way I wanted, I needed to move the menu to the bottom. This makes my pointer looses the "hover" and the menu gets closed.

Someone knows a solution for this? If I remove the arrow, everything will work fine, but I really liked the way it looks now!

[image: Menu drop-down]

The menu CSS:

```
nav ul {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%; 
}

nav li {  
    float: left;  
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 60px; 
    position: relative;
} 

nav ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
}

nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 15px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s;
    -transition: opacity 2s;
}

nav li ul li {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%; 
}

nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    background: #001a33;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

The arrow:

```
.arrow-up {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #001a33;
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    -webkit-transiton: opacity 2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2;
    -ms-transition: opacity 2s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2s;
    -transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="index.php">Início</a></li>
                . . .
                <li><a href="#">Desafios</a>
                <ul> <div class="arrow-up"></div>
                    <li><a href="repeticao.php">Repetição</a></li>
                <li><a href="desafio-imagem.php">Imagem</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your HTML structure and not that arrow.
You can simply put both drop-down element and the drop-down opener element (In your example "Desafios" link) beside each other and then append hover event to their parent.

Take a look at this example:

```
.menu {position: relative;}
.open-it {background: none; border: 1px solid gray; padding: 5px;}
.drop-down-list {
  display: none;
  position: relative; top: 100%; left: 0; padding: 5px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid gray; list-style: none;
}
.menu:hover > .drop-down-list {display: block !important;}

<div class="menu">
  <button class="open-it">Open it</button>
  <ul class="drop-down-list">
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2wwtfvey/1/

The trick is position drop-down element relatively so the parent could recognize it's child. And finally add an arrow and position it absolutly to `.open-it` element.